# Dataframe vs table

Tags: database, pandas

Is there a reason why pandas chose to use the term DataFrame instead of a Table?

I've looked this up a bit, and [Is a Dataframe Just a Table?](https://plateau-workshop.org/assets/papers-2019/10.pdf) was an interesting read. But even in the pandas documentation itself it often uses the two words interchangeable, such as:

> To manually store data in a table, create a `DataFrame`.

And:

> Similar to spreadsheet software, pandas represents data as a table with columns and rows.

Why did the library then choose to use this word instead of Table? Did it sort of 'inherit' this type from another library that made this choice, or was it something else?

Comment: Probably ripping off R.

Comment: _why pandas chose to use the term DataFrame instead of a Table_ would appear to be opinion based. Regardless, a dataframe is not a table (in the relational sense of the word)

Comment: IMHO a table is a data structure or rows and columns.  Going all the way back to Codd in 1970.  When you layer on top of it all the functionality it's set of classes that supports functions on a table.  This is when it is a data frame

Comment: a dataframe has inherent order. A table does not

Comment: The term data frame comes from R. Pandas was designed look and work like base R. A data frame is different from a table because a table is a 2-D object whereas a data frame is a set of 1D vectors bound together with a lot of functionality built on top such that it mimics a table.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, Table is a way too generic a name for a class. As Pandas is mostly used for Data Analysis purposes, using the word `Data` made sense. You might ask why not use the name `DataTable`?

One might see the usage of this word quite commonly in the UI world. But when it comes to Data Science and statistics, since the R programming language's first appearance in 1993 the usage of the term `frame` has been quite popular, and in fact, it is still being used by many Statisticians and Data Scientists. This history and logical attributes are what I think contributed to the coining of the name `DataFrame`.